# Deutsches oder deutsches Reich?

Tags: adjective, capitalization, proper-noun

> wie Hitler ein riesiges **Deutsches Reich** in Europa aufbauen wollte und..

Was ist der Grund dafür, *deutsch* mit einem Großbuchstaben zu schreiben?
Ist *Deutsch* ein Adjektiv oder nicht? Steckt dahinter eine Regel oder Erklärung?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das **Deutsche Reich** ist ein Eigenname und wird deswegen großgeschrieben, obwohl deutsch ein Adjektiv ist. Genauso wird auch das **Dritte Reich** als Eigenname großgeschrieben.

In anderen Fällen, die kein Eigenname sind, wird deutsch wie gewohnt klein geschrieben. Das deutsche Kind, der deutsche Mann, die deutsche Frau.

Nachzulesen ist das z.B. hier: [Duden/deutsch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deutsch). Dort findet man auch das Beispiel für das Deutsche Reich, unter *2. Bestandteil von Namen und bestimmten namenähnlichen Fügungen*

Comment: Wäre es nicht gerade deswegen an dieser Stelle viel angemessener, "ein riesiges, deutsches Reich" zu schreiben?

Comment: Wenn Hitler nachgedacht hätte ob er ein deutsches, britisches oder französisches Reich aufbauen wollte, dann ja. Aber das wollte er nicht. Er wollte ein Deutsches Reich.

Answer (score 8):

Die Regel zu Eigennamen, die hier Anwendung findet ist $60 des [amtlichen Regelwerks](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf).

Diese besagt

> In  mehrteiligen  Eigennamen  mit nichtsubstantivischen Bestandteilen schreibt  man das erste  Wort und alle weiteren  Wörter außer Artikel, Präpositionen und Konjunktionen groß
>
> Ein  vorangestellter  Artikel ist  in  der  Regel  nicht  Bestandteil  des Eigennamens und wird darum kleingeschrieben.

Daraus folgen sowohl

> das Deutsche Reich

als auch etwa

> die Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika